# me arroja este error al arrancar la app

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les adjunto la imagen del problema que arroja al arrancar la aplicación!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que **key** es nulo, entonces cuando haces `.child(key)` no puede pasarle nulo a esa referencia, chequea donde pones el valor y si lo estas asignando adentro de tu `onCreate()` antes de llamar a `productDetail(key)`